# gRPC set-buffer-hint for better performance

Tags: c++, grpc

Here I find the gRPC performance best practice: https://grpc.io/docs/guides/performance/

One of the items is:

(Special topic) Enable write batching in streams if message k + 1 does not rely on responses from message k by passing a WriteOptions argument to Write with buffer_hint set:
stream_writer->Write(message, WriteOptions().set_buffer_hint());

But I find if I stream messages one by one, and the message size is less than buffer size, then stream_writer->Write() will be blocked forever.

I want to know am I using it wrong? Or how should it be used?

Answer (score 0):

I got it: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/12975

According to the issue, it's not suggested to use this API for sync gRPC.